# JavaScript getElementById returns NULL in asp.net

Tags: javascript

I have been struggling for a few days on this, but I have had no luck.

The problem is this, I have a detailsview which is part of a view in a multiview, but more importantly, nested inside my detailsview are a number of controls. Of these controls, I am interested in 3 of them, two dropdownlists and a textbox. On one of my dropdownlists I have attached a javascript function which works on the onchange event when the user selects a value from the dropdownlist

Now, on my javascript function, I can get value from my dropdownlist when the user selects a value using "this" as the passed parameter. However, on the other two remaining controls, the textbox and the other dropdownlist, I am unable to get the control.

I have tried the following code snippets (this has been used on both controls):

```
document.getElementById('<%= dv.FindControl("ddlTrust.ClientID") %>'); //this returns null

document.getElementById('<%= ddlTrust.ClientID %>'); //errors - says that control has not been declared

document.getElementById("ddlTrust"); //this returns null
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure there is one (and only one) element with the ID `ddlTrust`?

Comment: What does the HTML output look like in the browser?

Comment: What's the output from your server-side code? If you're definite that the problem is client-side, that's the bit you need to look at.

Answer (score 0):

`dv.FindControl("ddlTrust.ClientID")` is going to look for a control with a client ID of `ddlTrust.ClientID`. That is why your first statement is returning null. But out of the 3 methods I think you were closest with this.

Personally I would recommend using jQuery when working with nested ASP.NET controls, it can make life a lot easier.

However, if you wish to use raw javascript, you could place the javascript inside the item template (so its repeated for each item), and do something like:

```
document.getElementById(<%=ControlID %>);
```

Then have `ControlID` as a global variable in your code behind and set the value of this on `dv` databound:

```
ControlID = ((DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("ddlTrust")).ClientID;
```

Comment: I have already tried the trick of placing in each of the insert template and the edit template of getElementById of the control, but this returns NULL to. I am not doing anything server side as it needs to be client side